# Why flutter version solving failed between firebase_core and firebase_messaging?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

In **pubspec.yaml**, if I use the following dependencies of *firebase_core* and *firebase_messaging* :

```yaml
dependencies:

  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
```

I get the following error message :

```
Because firebase_messaging >=7.0.3 <8.0.0-dev.7 depends on firebase_core ^0.5.0+1 and yourApp depends on firebase_core ^0.7.0, firebase_messaging >=7.0.3 <8.0.0-dev.7 is forbidden.
So, because youApp depends on firebase_messaging ^7.0.3, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because chat_app depends on firebase_messaging ^7.0.3, version solving failed.)
```

Answer (score 4):

Update your **pubspec.yaml** according to the migration guide to FlutterFire :
https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration/

*Caution:* At the time of writting, FlutterFire  Migration Guide does not compiled with *firebase_core 0.7.0* and *firebase_messaging 7.0.0*, that's why I suggested to use *firebase_messaging 8.0.0-dev* :

```yaml
dependencies:

  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  firebase_messaging: ^8.0.0-dev.14
```

Comment: The migration guide you linked to mentions firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3

Comment: I don't remember if the Flutter Migration Guide used firebase_messaging: ^8.0.0-dev.14, but I am sur it was not working  properly with firebase_core: ^7.0.0 and  firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3. Keep us in touch if it works now

Comment: Yeah the migration guide says 7.0.3, but it doesnt compile. using 8.0.0-dev.14 worked. So the guide is wrong I guess. You can mention it in your answer

Answer (score 2):

Just try with clean and remove **pubspec.lock** (kindly take backup)

```
flutter clean
pub cache repair  // optional
```

and this then update your **pubspec.yaml**, this works for me (Y)

```
dependencies:

  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  firebase_messaging: ^8.0.0-dev.14
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it

```
dependencies:

  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  firebase_messaging:
```

It will use the latest version of firebase_messaging